# Navbar expanding button does not work on Home Page

Tags: javascript, client, navbar, next.js13

Thanks for your time!

I am creating a responsive navbar, as a components in `/components/Header.js` and imported it in the `/app/layout.js`. But the problem is that the button to expand menu on mobile devices does not work in `/app/page.js` web page. However, it works in every other file such as `/pages/compressed.js` and etc.

I know that **onClick and useState** etc work only on **client components**, so I have written `use client` on the top of the code in `components/Header.js` file as show in the following code.

`/components/Header.js`

```
'use client';
import Image from "next/image"
import icon from '@public/favicon.png'
import Link from "next/link"
// import ClientComponent from "./ClientComponent";
import { useState } from "react"

const Header=()=> {
  const [navBar,setNavBar]  = useState(false)
  return (
    // <ClientComponent>
    <header className='sticky flex flex-col md:flex-row top-0 z-10 bg-white outline outline-1 outline-slate-200'>
    <Link href='/'>
        <div className='flex flex-row p-0 items-center justify-items-center justify-self-center'>
        <Image alt='' className='h-20 w-20' src={icon}/>
        <h1 className='pl-30 text-3xl font-semibold text-transparent bg-clip-text bg-gradient-to-r from-green-700 to-yellow-700'>LocalNAS</h1> 
        </div></Link> 
        <ul className='hidden md:flex flex flex-row align-items-center justify-center'>
          <li className='hover-underline-animation text-zinc-600 font-medium'><Link href="/" className="text-center">Home</Link></li>
          <li className='hover-underline-animation text-zinc-600 font-medium'><Link href="/documents" className="text-center">Documents</Link></li>
          <li className='hover-underline-animation text-zinc-600 font-medium'><Link href="/media" className="text-center">Media</Link></li>
          <li className='hover-underline-animation text-zinc-600 font-medium'><Link href="/compressed" className="text-center">Compressed</Link></li>
        </ul>
        <button className="md:hidden" key="hek" onClick={()=>setNavBar((prev)=> !prev)}>
          Button
        </button>
        {
        navBar&&(
        <div>
        <ul className='md:hidden  md:flex flex flex-col'>
          <li className='hover-underline-animation text-zinc-600 font-medium'><Link href="/">Home</Link></li>
          <li className='hover-underline-animation text-zinc-600 font-medium'><Link href="/documents">Documents</Link></li>
          <li className='hover-underline-animation text-zinc-600 font-medium'><Link href="/media">Media</Link></li>
          <li className='hover-underline-animation text-zinc-600 font-medium'><Link href="/compressed">Compressed</Link></li>
        </ul>
        </div>)}
      </header>
      // </ClientComponent>
  )
}

export default Header
```

But, **button** still does not work on home page **only**. I have imported it like following in the `layout.js` file.

`/app/layout.js`:

```
import '@styles/globals.css'
import { figtree } from '@/components/fonts';
import Header from '@/components/Header';

export const metadata = {
  title: 'LocalNAS',
  description: 'An incomplete project!'
}

function RootLayout ({children}){
  return (
    <html>
      <main className={figtree.className}>
      <Header/>
      <div>{children}</div>
      </main>
    </html>
  )
}

export default RootLayout;
```

and the `/app/page.js` file is as below:

```
import HomeData from '@/components/HomeData';
import PageHeading from '@/components/pageHeading';
import getData from './getData';




export default async function Home(){
  const compressedFiles =await getData('http://192.168.10.22:5000/compressedFiles')
  const bookFiles =await getData('http://192.168.10.22:5000/bookFiles')
  const zipFiles =await getData('http://192.168.10.22:5000/zipFiles')
  const imageFiles =await getData('http://192.168.10.22:5000/imageFiles')
  const videoFiles =await getData('http://192.168.10.22:5000/videoFiles')
  const officeFiles =await getData('http://192.168.10.22:5000/officeFiles')

  
  const groups = [
  { name: "Documents", array: bookFiles.slice(0, 6).concat(officeFiles.slice(0, 6)) },
  { name: "Compressed", array: compressedFiles.slice(0, 3).concat(zipFiles.slice(0,3)) },
  { name: "Media", array: videoFiles.slice(0, 3).concat(imageFiles.slice(0,3)) },
]

  return (
    <div>
      <PageHeading heading="Share documents, media, and other files over the Local Wifi Network."/>
      <div>
      <HomeData Files={groups.at(0)}/><hr className='mx-10 mb-10 sm:mx-20 md:mx-40' />
      <HomeData Files={groups.at(1)}/><hr className='mx-10 mb-10 sm:mx-20 md:mx-40' />
      <HomeData Files={groups.at(2)}/>
      </div>  
    </div>
  )
}

//  Home;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for their help and thinking!

I have solved the problem by moving from **home page** file from `/app/page.js` to the **pages** dir as `/pages/index.js`.

Answer (score 1):

1.Move the Data Fetching to getServerSideProps or getStaticProps:

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const compressedFiles = await getData('http://192.168.10.22:5000/compressedFiles');
  // ... fetch other data ...

  const groups = [
    { name: "Documents", array: bookFiles.slice(0, 6).concat(officeFiles.slice(0, 6)) },
    // ... other groups ...
  ];

  return {
    props: {
      groups
    }
  };
}
```

Then, in your `Home` component, you can access groups via props:

```
export default function Home({ groups }) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: The element does not show with the second step

Comment: without {ssr:false} it shows

Comment: ok so dont use the ssr: false. if you dont use its work?

Comment: "getServerSideProps" is not supported in app/