# Nextjs client-side rendering not working?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, client-side-rendering

I have created a project in nextjs 13 using app router. I want to acheive client-side rendering. In their documentation it is mentioned that for rendering on client-side, add 'use client' at the top of file and that will be rendered on client-side.
but unfortunately i am not able to have its effects of client-side. i am stuck with that.

This is my page.js file:

```
'use client';

import { useState } from 'react'

export default function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  console.log("counter")

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  )
 }
```

It should be rendered on client-side but it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed that issue, actually i installed nodejs updated version with old nvm version. i updated my nvm version and install nodejs, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Migrate your `app/page.js` to `pages/index.js`, and see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: i have a sparate project with page routes, that works fine with client-side but it's not working with app router.

Comment: [Read This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77031673/navbar-expanding-button-does-not-work-on-home-page)

Comment: but if i move page.js to pages directory, it would be page router in that case, but i want to acheive it through app routes.

Comment: You are right it works on page router but not on app router.

Comment: i have created new project many times but still with app router its not working.

Comment: Try adding `onClick={()=>{console.log("log"}}` on any other element and check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "It should be rendered on client-side but it's not."? Do you receive the following error: "You're importing a component that needs useState. It only works in a Client Component but none of its parents are marked with "use client", so they're Server Components by default.
Learn more: [https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials"](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials%22)?
if not, and the counter increses when you click the button, the component is rendered on client side

Also, are you using the latest version of Next.JS?

Comment: Yes i am using 'nextjs: 13.4.19' and Yes, if i remove 'use client' from the top of file, i get this erorr.

Comment: But, if you have "use client" at the top of the file, the page works correctly. This means that the component is rendered on the client side, because the useState hook is only available for client side components

Comment: Yes you are right. but if i use 'useEffect' hook and console anything inside 'useEffect' it does not work. it does not console anything on client-side.

Comment: Also that button does not do anything, although i have an 'onClick' listener on it but this listener does not fire when i click on button.

Comment: useEffect is called after the first render and every time the dependencies changes. if you have an empty array as dependencies useEffect will be called only on the first render. otherwise, if you put count on the dependencies array, useEffect will be called every time you click teh button (because count changes)

Comment: you are right, but here the case is that button 'onClick' listener is not firing up. due to which state is also not updating. and also if i write 'useEffect(() => {
    console.log("count")
  }, []). it should console count atleast once after first render but its not even working that way.

Comment: i have copy and pasted your code in a nextjs project and all works fine in the app dir. also, if you want to print the string "count" every time you click on the button, you should use `useEffect(() => { console.log("count") }, [count])`

Comment: what else could be the reason for me not getting the correct output.
this is my package.json:
{
  "name": "new-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "13.4.19",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  }
}

Comment: try to create a new nextjs project and see if it works.

Comment: i have tried this 3 times and still im getting this problem

Answer (score 0):

If you have `<main></main>` tag in the `layout.js` file change it to `<body></body` and see if this resolves your issue. If not tell me, how you call your onClick function.

Another Solution:
Try updating the `nodejs` and `nextjs` by running :

`yarn add next@latest react@latest react-dom@latest`

Thanks

Comment: its already in <body> tag.
this is my layout.js file.
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}

Comment: Try this: `onClick={() => {setCount(count + 1)}}`

Comment: no this not effecting, i already have this one.

Comment: Update your Next JS by running `yarn add next@latest react@latest react-dom@latest

`